# Convertir a mayusculas las teclas que van siendo pulsadas de cualquier input

Tags: javascript

Quisiera que al ir escribiendo las teclas se fueran convirtiendo a Mayúsculas, tomando en cuenta de que se pueda hacer con cualquier input del formulario, es decir, que la formula sea general.

tengo lo siguiente:

```js
function mayus(e) {

    var tecla=e.value;
    var tecla2=tecla.toUpperCase();
    
    alert(tecla2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="mayus(this);">
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

En lugar de usar `onKeyPress`, te recomiendo que uses `onKeyUp`, esta actua, cuando tu dejas de presionar la tecla.

Asi que lo unico que hacemos es, usando la function `toUpperCase()` convertiremos toda la cadena en general, y le dara el efecto que se hace una por una, ya que en cada evento del `onKeyUp()` se ejecutara la funcion.

Osea, no es necesario convertir a mayuscula letra por letra.

Igual, puedes replicar la funcion en otros `<input type='text'>` y funcionara igual, asi que no hay inconveniente en que sea general.

```js
function mayus(e) {
    e.value = e.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="mayus(this);">
<input type="text" onkeyup="mayus(this);">
```

Otra forma de solucionarlo seria asi:

Al crear el `<input type='text'>`, le asignas un `id` a cada uno, y posteriormente puedes aplicar esta formula.

```html
<input type="text" id="campo" onKeyUp="document.getElementById(this.id).value=document.getElementById(this.id).value.toUpperCase()">
```

Comment: muchas gracias :), perfecto.

Estaba tratando de hacer algo como document.getelementbyi(trhis).teclamayus

Comment: @VictorA. Espero te haya servido, lo que comentas podria funcionar, recuerda que en programacion, un problema tiene muchas formas de solucionarse

Comment: @VictorA. He agregado otra forma que te podria servir, basada en la que tu has sugerido, solo que con algunas modificaciones

Comment: gracias.

no sabia que se colocaba (this.id)

Comment: @VictorA. Seguramente te faltaba el `this.id`, recuerda que `this` es un objeto y `document.getElementById` necesita el `id` del elemento

Comment: Si te ha servido la pregunta, no olvides **aceptarla**, recuerda que esto ayuda a nuestra comunidad a convertirse en una **base de conocimiento**, para los programadores de habla hispana. Ya que cualquier usuario en un **futuro** puede tener un problema similar al tuyo.

Comment: Exacto me faltaba eso. Sorry no la habia aceptado jajajaja, el mouse esta dañao

Comment: Buena solución, solo acotar que el evento keyup puede reducirse a `onKeyUp="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()"` causando el mismo efecto pero sin recorrer el DOM buscandose a si mismo como elemento.

Comment: @nerdcoder Gracias por tu comentario! Lo magico de la programacion, es que un problema tiene mas soluciones que lineas de codigo :)

Answer (score 4):

La forma mas sencilla sin tener que llamar javascript solo incluye esta linea en tu css:

```
input{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

y listo.

Comment: De hecho funciona... pero solo es para "Diseño Vista"

Answer (score 3):

Con [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) puedes cambiar a Mayúsculas el texto de cualquier `<input>` o `<textarea>` , prueba el siguiente código insertándolo en la cabecera (`<head>`) del documento:

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready( function () {
      $("input").on("keypress", function () {
       $input=$(this);
       setTimeout(function () {
        $input.val($input.val().toUpperCase());
       },50);
      })
     })
    </script>
```

Puedes también usar [CSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoja_de_estilos_en_cascada) para indicar que `<input>` o `<textarea>` quieres convertir a Mayúsculas:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
 $(".UpperCase").on("keypress", function () {
  $input=$(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
   $input.val($input.val().toUpperCase());
  },50);
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <h1>Datos de Contacto</h1>
 <pre>
  codigo    <input name="codigo">
  nombre    <input name="nombre" class="UpperCase">
  dirección <input name="direccion">
  teléfono  <input name="telefono">
  cargo     <input name="cargo" class="UpperCase">
 </pre>
<form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema. Sin embargo yo tengo un desarrollo usando WebForms en ASP.Net.

Para complicar las cosas estoy usando los controles de DevExpress. Y como están hechos sus "inputs" (o TextBoxes) en base a tablas tuve que hacerlo de esta forma:

1. Primero en el control ASPxTextBox busqué el evento del lado del cliente KeyUp, como lo sugirió Iván Botero. Se puede encontrar teniendo seleccionado el control en la vista de diseño en la Ventana propiedades como ClientSideEvents. Se despliega el nodo y seleccionamos el evento KeyUp
2. Al abrirse la ventana se escribe la función de forma parecida a como nuestro compañero nos lo propuso. En este caso yo lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function convierteTextoAMayusculas(s, e) {
    s.inputElement.value = s.inputElement.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Decidí hacerlo así porque esa función la tengo en un documento de javascript aparte, ya que lo pienso reutilizar en otras áreas del documento y en otros documentos. De hecho yo recomendaría seguir con el patrón que nos sugieren los mismos controles de DevExpress para que todo sea más claro, como en el siguiente:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="xtxtMiTextBox" runat="server" Width="170px">
    <ClientSideEvents KeyUp="function(s, e) { convierteTextoAMayusculas(s, e); }" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

De esta manera podemos notar que obtenemos la referencia al control que invoca el evento en su argumento source (s) para trabajar con él.

Muchas gracias por las anteriores respuestas, fueron muy útiles.

Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Este lo uso yo (leyendo el evento `keyup`) y me funciona sin problemas:

```js
$('#ordenName').keyup(function() {
  var datos = new String($('#ordenName').val());
  datos = datos.toUpperCase(datos);
  $('#lblOrden').html(datos);
  $('#ordenName').val(datos);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Usted esta escribiendo esto: <span id="lblOrden"></span></p>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="norden" id="ordenName">
```

Comment: por favor considera añadir una explicación, solo poner código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: añade comentarios luego de cada linea del código para que ayudes a las personas que podrían no entender jquery del todo, gracias por el aporte

Comment: La pregunta hace referencia a JavaScript, no jQuery!

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de gran utilidad para otros usuarios. Por faovr lee [answer] y edita la respuesta para añadir una breve descripción de lo que hace y cómo funciona. También completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio y con ello ganar una nueva medalla.

Answer (score 1):

Como anteriormente mencionan, puedes hacerlo en una sola línea de CSS así:

```css
input, textarea { text-transform: uppercase }
```

Pero esto solo será visualmente ya que si recuperas el `value` del input te lo regresara con mayúsculas y minúsculas respectivamente a como las escribió el usuario.

Si quieres recuperar todo el texto en mayúsculas con javascript lo puedes hacer transformando asignándole al `value` del input, este mismo pero transformado con el método `toUpperCase` de los `strings` en el evento `keyup`

```js
const $input = document.querySelector('input')

$input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Ahora si lo quieres hacer en todos los `input`'s y `textarea`'s puedes hacerlo seleccionando todos y asignándole la misma función.

```js
const $inputsAndTextareas = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea')

const handleKeyup = (event) => {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.toUpperCase()
}

const addHandleKeyup = ($element) => {
  $element.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyup)
}

$inputsAndTextareas.forEach(addHandleKeyup)
```

```html
<input type="text" />

<textarea></textarea>

<input type="text" />
```